# How to make basic TCP/IP connections where nc(1) is not available?

Tags: linux, networking, unix, opensuse

I'm maintaining an outdated server where nc(1) is not available and installing new tools is also not an option. I've to use basic UNIX tools in order to do what nc(1) does. The system is a SuSE 11.1. How can I do that with standard UNIX tools? I'm actually looking for a portable solution which I could use anywhere.

Comment: Define "basic UNIX tools", "standard UNIX tools" and "portable". Usually these mean "specified by POSIX". AFAIK POSIX does not specify command line tools that could replace `nc`. It specifies a C compiler (`c99`, earlier `c89`). It doesn't mean some compiler is installed in the OS in question. Still some compiler may be the best you can get. Is any compiler available? Do you want to listen? or only initiate connections? Non-portable possibilities: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/440018/108618) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49936/108618).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on that you want to do. if you want to listen to a port, that is not easily done. I'm not sure if it's possible at all.

But if you want to connect send data, here you go:

```
alias bashnc="(exec 3<>/dev/tcp/<targethost>/<port>; cat >&3; cat <&3; exec 3<&-)"
echo "Hello world!" | bashnc
```

Just replace  and .